# My internal microphone doesn't work on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: lenovo

I have tried to search for lots of solutions but none of them worked.

I have a dual boot system Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 the mic works fine on Windows 10 but not working on Ubuntu 20.04 and I have a Lenovo Ideapad 520 laptop.

How can I get the mic to work, please?